# Column number of window.onerror

Tags: javascript, error-handling, dom-events

Is it possible to retrieve the **column number** when catching the JavaScript `window.onerror` event?

Due to minifying, the line number itself often is just very little to no information in finding the actual error position in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the browser implementation.
You may simply check for it and use it if defined.
You can even get the error and thus the stacktrace on some 'modern' browsers.
There are many articles on the subject of `onerror` but many are outdated, here is a recent one:

https://bugsnag.com/blog/js-stacktraces/

There also seem to be some libraries that help you with this like tracekit.js

Comment: Thank you. In some browsers, it is simply an additional parameter I found out.

Comment: Yes, you can use it if it is defined.